# aws ec2 import-image fails with error "ClientError: Unknown OS / Missing OS files."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

While converting from montavista vmdk (virtual machine disk image) to aws ec2 AMI, getting below error,

```
    "Description": "import-VMDKs", 
    "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Unknown OS / Missing OS files.", 
    "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-fh8l0rmf"
```

Would like to know whether AWS supports MontaVista Linux or am I missing any files in VMDK image.

Answer (score 3):

As of this posting, Montavista linux is not supported.

Import supports the following linux distros (64 bit), according to [AWS Documentation: VM Import/Export Prerequisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html#prerequisites):

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 5.1-5.11, 6.1-6.6, 7.0-7.1
- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server

  - SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 Service Pack 1 - 2.6.32.12-0.7
  - SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 Service Pack 2 - 3.0.13-0.27
  - SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 Service Pack 3 - 3.0.76-0.11, 3.0.101-0.8, and 3.0.101-0.15
  - SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 Service Pack 4 - 3.0.101-63
  - SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 - 3.12.28-4
  - SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 Service Pack 1 - 3.12.49-11
- Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 13.10, 14.04, 14.10, 15.04
- CentOS 5.1-5.11, 6.1-6.6, 7.0-7.1
- Debian 6.0.0-6.0.8, 7.0.0-7.8.0, 8.0.0
- Oracle Linux 6.1-6.6, 7.0-7.1
- Fedora Server 19-21